# GeoServer + PostGIS performance

Tags: postgis, geoserver, performance, docker

Testing a GeoServer performance. Using a Kartoza docker image and data is under AWS RDS instance for PostgreSQL.

The size of the PostgreSQL materialized view is Size 3,666 MB.

Spatial indexes and unique field are on it.

Using the simple layer preview, I noticed it takes about 30 minutes to render that one layer. Not sure where the bottleneck is yet.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mcte/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=mcte%3Acounties_multipolygon_mv&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A404000&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=330&BBOX=-270%2C-76.640625%2C270%2C155.390625
```

[image]

I know it's a large table with multipolygons geometry in it. Total number of features are 2610645. It's also has a history data going back year or two Total # of vertices are 171332556.

Unfortunately due to the nature of data, caching is not an option.

How do I improve the rendering performance ?

Comment: 4GB could be a small, medium, or large layer. Of much greater use would be information about the number of features, topology class, vertices per feature,...

Comment: What is your question?  I'm assuming that there must be one but best if you mark it.